# How to mock open when is used in another method?

Tags: ruby, rspec, open-uri

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def set_container_bg
  open(self.page.permanent_screenshot) do |file|
    # some logic with file
  end
end
```

And I am trying to create a rspec test, but I want to mock the open method inside set_container_bg, so that it returns something that I expect?

When I say it returns, I mean that `'file'` is something I know how to manage.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Since Kernel gets mixed into the object you are testing, you could just stub the `open` method in the object you are testing.

Imagine you are testing an object called `container`, something like this should do the trick:

```
file = double(File)
container.stub(:open) { |&block| block.yield file }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `file` object, the below would pass

```
Object.any_instance.stub(:open).with(anything()).and_return file
open(self.page.permanent_screenshot).should eq file
```